# Aplicação Java SE muito lenta com BD MySQL remoto, como otimizar?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans, jdbc

Olá, pessoas. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação desktop com Java SE e testando o software com um banco de dados remoto ele fica muito lento, enquanto que com o banco de dados local funciona normalmente. A seguir segue um método de exemplo de como estou programando o CRUD (esse método também é o que mais demora para retornar a resposta quando a conexão é remota):

```
public List<EscolaTecnicaModel> pesquisar(EscolaTecnicaModel escolaTecnicaModel) throws Exception {
    Connection conexao = Conexao.abrirConexao();
    List<EscolaTecnicaModel> escolas = new ArrayList<>();
    String sqlSelect = "SELECT " +
                           "et.*, ad.usuario, ad.senha, c.nome AS nome_cidade, c.id_estado, e.nome AS nome_estado, e.codigo_uf " +
                       "FROM escolas_tecnicas et " +
                           "INNER JOIN administradores ad ON (et.id_administrador = ad.id_administrador) " +
                           "INNER JOIN cidades c ON (et.id_cidade = c.id_cidade) " +
                           "INNER JOIN estados e ON (c.id_estado = e.id_estado) "; 
    String sqlWhere = "";
    String sqlOrder = "ORDER BY et.nome ASC"; 

    if (!escolaTecnicaModel.getNome().trim().equals("")) {
        sqlWhere += "WHERE et.nome LIKE '%" + escolaTecnicaModel.getNome() + "%' "; 
    }       

    PreparedStatement psBuscarEscolas = conexao.prepareStatement(sqlSelect + sqlWhere + sqlOrder);
    ResultSet rsBuscaEscolas = psBuscarEscolas.executeQuery();

    if (rsBuscaEscolas.next()) {
        do {
            EscolaTecnicaModel escolaTecnica = new EscolaTecnicaModel();
            escolaTecnica.setIdEscolaTecnica(rsBuscaEscolas.getInt("id_escola"));
            escolaTecnica.setNome(rsBuscaEscolas.getString("nome"));
            escolaTecnica.setEmail(rsBuscaEscolas.getString("email"));
            escolaTecnica.setIdAdministrador(rsBuscaEscolas.getInt("id_administrador"));
            escolaTecnica.setUsuario(rsBuscaEscolas.getString("usuario"));
            escolaTecnica.setSenha(rsBuscaEscolas.getString("senha"));
            escolaTecnica.setNivel(AdministradorModel.Nivel.ESCOLA);
            escolaTecnica.getCidade().setIdCidade(rsBuscaEscolas.getInt("id_cidade"));
            escolaTecnica.getCidade().setNome(rsBuscaEscolas.getString("nome_cidade"));
            escolaTecnica.getCidade().getEstado().setIdEstado(rsBuscaEscolas.getInt("id_estado"));
            escolaTecnica.getCidade().getEstado().setNome(rsBuscaEscolas.getString("nome_estado"));
            escolaTecnica.getCidade().getEstado().setCodigoUf(rsBuscaEscolas.getString("codigo_uf"));
            escolaTecnica.getEndereco().setRua(rsBuscaEscolas.getString("rua"));
            escolaTecnica.getEndereco().setNumero(rsBuscaEscolas.getString("numero"));
            escolaTecnica.getEndereco().setBairro(rsBuscaEscolas.getString("bairro"));
            escolaTecnica.getEndereco().setCep(rsBuscaEscolas.getString("cep") == null ? "" : rsBuscaEscolas.getString("cep"));

            PreparedStatement psBuscarTelefones = conexao.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM telefones_escolas_tecnicas WHERE id_escola = ?");
            psBuscarTelefones.setInt(1, escolaTecnica.getIdEscolaTecnica());
            ResultSet rsBuscarTelefones = psBuscarTelefones.executeQuery();

            while (rsBuscarTelefones.next()) {
                TelefoneModel telefone = new TelefoneModel();
                telefone.setDdd(rsBuscarTelefones.getString("ddd"));
                telefone.setNumero(rsBuscarTelefones.getString("numero"));
                telefone.setTipo(rsBuscarTelefones.getString("tipo"));

                escolaTecnica.adicionarTelefone(telefone);
            }

            escolas.add(escolaTecnica);

            Conexao.fecharConexao(rsBuscarTelefones, psBuscarTelefones);
        } while (rsBuscaEscolas.next());
    } else {
        Conexao.fecharConexao(conexao, psBuscarEscolas, rsBuscaEscolas);

        throw new Exception("Nenhuma escola encontrada");
    }

    Conexao.fecharConexao(conexao, psBuscarEscolas, rsBuscaEscolas);

    return escolas;
}
```

O que pode estar causando essa lentidão e como solucionar?

Comment: Eu penso que o problema aqui e o facto de estares a fazer a conexao na mesma Thread onde estas a tratar os dados, sabendo que tens varios loops imbutidos talvez seria boa ideia recuperar o teu ResultSet e tratar-lo em separado de forma assíncrona So uma uma sugestao Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Esse método é só um exemplo de como estrou abrindo, manipulando e fechando a conexão, mas há outros com somente um loop que também estão demorando para retornar dados (demoram menos que esse do exemplo, óbvio, mas demoram).

Comment: faz indice para essas querys

Comment: O problema estava na chamada desses métodos para a exibição dos dados na interface gráfica. Eu havia feito algumas chamadas redundantes dentro de loops, que acabaram virando uma bola de neve... A forma como os eventos são executados no Swing também prejudicam um pouco, mas já consegui melhorar bastante a performance. Obrigado pela disponibilidade em ajudar.